# Celery showing django's runserver logs instead of celery logs

Tags: python, django, docker, celery, celerybeat

I have a dockerized Django project and everything works fine because Celery keeps displaying runserver logs instead of celery logs.

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    api:
        container_name: api
        restart: always
        build: .
        networks:
            - API_NETWORK
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - database
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        command: bash -c /entrypoint.sh

    database:
        container_name: postgres
        restart: always
        image: postgres:latest
        networks:
            - API_NETWORK
        volumes:
            - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust

    redis:
        container_name: redis
        image: redis:latest
        networks:
            - API_NETWORK

    celery:
        container_name: celery
        restart: always
        build: .
        networks:
            - API_NETWORK
        depends_on:
            - api
            - redis
            - database
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        command: celery -A dir_name worker -l debug

    celery-beat:
        container_name: celery-beat
        restart: always
        build: .
        networks:
            - API_NETWORK
        depends_on:
            - api
            - redis
            - database
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        command: celery -A dir_name beat -l debug --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler

volumes:
    pgdata:

networks:
    API_NETWORK:
        name: API_NETWORK
        driver: bridge
```

...and here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential git gcc python3-dev \
    && python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN mkdir /dir_name
WORKDIR /dir_name
COPY . /dir_name

RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt

RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]
```

The issue is instead of getting proper Celery logs in the `celery` container, I keep getting django's `runserver` command logs:

```
celery         | Running migrations:
celery         |   No migrations to apply.
celery         | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
celery         | Performing system checks...
celery         | 
celery         | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
celery         | June 08, 2021 - 02:41:29
celery         | Django version 3.1.7, using settings 'cnapi.settings'
celery         | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
celery         | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

If I open a shell in the container the run the celery command, it works fine. But why isn't it working from scratch? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the **`ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]`** from your Dockerfile and rebuild your images again.

I hope that will do the job.